# How to fetch contacts from Gmail

Tags: java, google-contacts-api

I have seen [Google Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) but I am not getting any thing I want to fetch email contacts from logged in users.

I found a [simple example with php](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/06/import-gmail-contacts-google-oauth.html) which is very easy but I am not able to convert it in to java. I am trying with [Google contact API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) problem is the import statement is showing error.

How to import these.

```
 import com.google.gdata.client.*;
 import com.google.gdata.client.contacts.*;
 import com.google.gdata.data.*;
 import com.google.gdata.data.contacts.*;
 import com.google.gdata.data.extensions.*;
 import com.google.gdata.util.*;
 import java.io.IOException;
```

I am not getting jar file for these imports. If is there any example other than google please give links.

Comment: Can you show us some code or a more detailed description of whats happening/not happening? How much have you do so far?

Comment: Tried to import code                                                         import com.google.gdata.client.*;
import com.google.gdata.client.contacts.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.contacts.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.extensions.*;
import com.google.gdata.util.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;                                                                        showing error

Comment: Update your post please and format it so it is easily readable. Tried this example? http://rajnautiyal.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/get-all-the-contacts-from-gmail-using-google-data-protocol/

Comment: all you need OAuth, use any Oauth API and let user authorize you to access his/her data.one simple yet power full OAuth API is [scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following maven entry:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
  <artifactId>gdata-contacts-3.0</artifactId>
  <version>1.41.5</version>
</dependency>
```

supported the following imports, which allowed me to access the gmail contacts

```
import com.google.gdata.client.Service.GDataRequest;
import com.google.gdata.client.contacts.ContactsService;
import com.google.gdata.data.Link;
import com.google.gdata.data.TextConstruct;
import com.google.gdata.data.contacts.Birthday;
import com.google.gdata.data.contacts.ContactEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.contacts.ContactFeed;
import com.google.gdata.data.extensions.Email;
import com.google.gdata.data.extensions.FamilyName;
import com.google.gdata.data.extensions.FormattedAddress;
import com.google.gdata.data.extensions.GivenName;
import com.google.gdata.data.extensions.Name;
import com.google.gdata.data.extensions.OrgName;
import com.google.gdata.data.extensions.Organization;
import com.google.gdata.data.extensions.PhoneNumber;
import com.google.gdata.data.extensions.StructuredPostalAddress;
import com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException;
import com.google.gdata.util.ContentType;
import com.google.gdata.util.PreconditionFailedException;
import com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException;
```